# Vue JSON.parse failing because of space?

Tags: vue.js, twig

I have the following json_encoded return value that I get from PHP

```
{"data":{"format":"d\/m\/Y H:i:s"}}
```

I pass this to my Vue application like this:

```
<component data={{ object.toJson() }}></component>
```

However, this gets transferred to Vue like this:

```
{"data":{"format":"d\/m\/Y" h:i:s&quot;}}
```

Why is this happening? I see the string just fine and OK in PHP, but not when it gets transferred to Vue

Comment: have you already tried the [raw filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/raw.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [raw filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/raw.html).

As Darkbee pointed out, you are also missing quotes. as example:

```
<component data="{{ object.toJson()|raw }}"></component>
```

Comment: When I use the raw filter, exactly as listed above, the component is not loaded at all. It simply is missing from the rendered html then

Comment: You might want to place quotes around the value

Comment: Thanks @DarkBee that was it!

Comment: Great! @ThomasVdBerge feel free to edit my answer with the working version of the code